<ProtocolError for localhost/RPC2: 404 Not Found>error message while starting Kiwi TCMS API Python script
I'm new in Kiwi TCMS system. I'm trying to use its API and got some troubles.
I'm using Docker compose version by using this documentation. My environment is Windows 10.
I made some simple Python program:

import ssl
from tcms_api import TCMS

def main():
    try:
        _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

    kiwi = TCMS(url = "https://localhost", username = "root", password = "Kiwi-root1").exec
    ver = kiwi.KiwiTCMS.version()
    test_run = kiwi.TestRun.filter({'id' : 1877})[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

On the kiwi.KiwiTCMS.version() call I got an error: <ProtocolError for localhost/RPC2: 404 Not Found> .
Could you, please, suggest me what is wrong?
I made test under Windows. Also I've configured Docket to use WSL2.
